# Parse data to custom data object in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

i am trying to use codable in swift 4 to parse comming data to custom object , but still do not know exactly .
This is my custom class :

```
class  Response_Model : Codable {
var id : String?
var code : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case id = "id"
    case code = "code"
}


init(){

    id = ""
    code = ""

}


required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
    code = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .code)
}


func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
    aCoder.encode(code, forKey: "code")
}}
```

And here i am trying to parse the resonse :

```
responseModel = try jsonDecoder.decode([Response_Model].self, from: result as! Data)
```

And this is response :

```
[
{
    "id": "38",
    "code": "code1"
},
{
    "id": "39",
    "code": "code2"
}]
```

Thank you

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: The decoding is not completed succecfully?

Comment: First of all you have to use like this -> `class  Response_Model : NSObject, Codable ` and second thing is that ask clear question.

Comment: Using your code above in a playground, I can successfully decode the JSON into the model and print out each value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too cumbersome, most of the boilerplate code the `Codable` protocol provides for free.

The class can be reduced to (by the way in most cases a `struct` is sufficient)

```
struct ResponseModel : Codable {
    var id : String
    var code : String
}
```

Now decode the JSON

```
let jsonString = """
  [
   {"id": "38", "code": "code1"},
   {"id": "39", "code": "code2"}
  ]
"""

do {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    let result = try  JSONDecoder().decode([ResponseModel].self, from: data)
    for item in result {
        print(item.code, item.id)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```